# How would I style these div tags to get a working comment section?

Tags: php, css

I've been having trouble for a few hours now trying to understand what I'm doing wrong with this styling.  I have a webpage that displays a user post on the left half, and the `comment-section` along with the comment form on the right half.  I have a `PostCommentSet` class that contains all `comments` and `replies`.  Right now, my comments are overlapping ontop of each other, they should be placed underneath the former so that both are visible.  If a comment has any replies, the reply should be placed below the same comment and then when there aren't any more replies to display, we continue with more comments.
Like this,

```
Comment 1
...Reply 1 of comment 1
...Reply 2 of comment 1
Comment 2
Comment 3
...Reply 1 of comment 3
Comment 4
etc..
```

There are elements within the comment and reply classes that have positioning, would that be what is messing it up?

If you have any questions about my code, I will be ready to answer them.

My CSS

```
.PostCommentSet {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 60px;
            width: 30%;
            height: calc(100vh - 207px);
            background-color: #777;
            padding: 10px 2.5% 0px 1%;
            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
.PostComments {
            background-color: #555;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: white;
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            position: static;
            z-index: 2;
            display: inline-block;
        }
.PostReplies {
            background-color: #555;
            padding: 10px;
            color: white;       
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 80%;
            height: auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            position: static;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

My Php / HTML

```
while ($commenterrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commenterresult)) {

                                echo    '<div class="PostCommentSet"> <div class="PostComments">';

                                    if ($commenterrow['profileimg'] == 1) {
                                        $filename = "profilepics/profile".$commenterid."*";
                                        $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                                        $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                                        $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                                        echo "<div class='CommentProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/profile".$commenterid.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "<div class='CommentProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/noUser.png'></div>";
                                    }
                                echo    "<div class='CommentUserName'>".$commenterrow['userName']."</div>";
                                echo    "<div class='CommenterComment'>".$commentrow['comment']."</div> </div>";
                            }
                            $currentcommentid = $commentrow['commentid'];
                            $replysql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hostid = '$hostid' AND postid = '$postid' AND commentid = '$currentcommentid' AND replyid > 0";
                            $replyresult = mysqli_query($conn, $replysql);
                            while ($replyrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($replyresult)) {
                                if (mysqli_num_rows($replyresult)==0) {
                                    echo '</div> <br>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    $replierid = $replyrow['userid'];
                                    $repliersql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$replierid'";
                                    $replierresult = mysqli_query($conn, $repliersql);
                                    while ($replierrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($replierresult)) {

                                        echo    '<div class="PostReplies">';

                                            if ($replierrow['profileimg'] == 1) {
                                                $filename = "profilepics/profile".$replierid."*";
                                                $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                                                $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                                                $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                                                echo "<div class='ReplyProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/profile".$replierid.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                echo "<div class='ReplyProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/noUser.png'></div>";
                                            }
                                    echo '
                                                <div class="ReplyUserName">'.$replierrow['userName'].'</div>
                                                <div class="ReplierReply">'.$replyrow['reply'].'</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty difficult here without seeing the rest of your css, but i'm confused as to why you're using `inline-block` level display on your `postReplies` and `postComments` elements. This attribute applies to the elements themselves, not their children within. I'd suggest changing both these to `block` display and see if that helps first. Also, there is no need to declare `position:static`.

The best thing you could do is strip out your markup and create a fiddle which duplicates your issue. From there it would be an easy fix. Otherwise, please post the css for your whole (relevant) markup.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry.  I knew it would be confusing mainly because I don't know what the problem is or where it starts.  I had it set to static because the parent element was set to absolute at one point and i thought i could reset it.  I think I found a start to the solution just now, im hoping it leads somewhere.  Thank you for your help :)